# How to make the UIButton title label font same in size regardless of the text width

Tags: ios, uibutton, font-size

I am generating few buttons that should look like a tabbar. This is what I have done.

```
scrolTab=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, h-48, w, 48)];
[scrolTab setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 180.0)];
[scrolTab setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[self.view addSubview:scrolTab];

for (int i=1; i<6; i++) {
    [scrolTab addSubview:[self GetTabBarItems:i :5]];
}
```

Then my GetTabBarItems method is like this.

```
-(UIButton *)GetTabBarItems :(NSInteger)index:(NSInteger)count
   {
      UIButton *item=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tabbuttonX, 0, w/count,49)];

[item.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:10.0]];
item.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
item.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
item.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;

CGSize imageSize=item.imageView.image.size;

CGFloat space=6.0;

if (index==1) {
    [item setTitle:@"Menu" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [item setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MenuBtn"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}



else if (index==2) {
    [item setTitle:@"My Profile" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [item setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ProfTab"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
else if (index==3) {
    [item setTitle:@"Notification" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [item setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Notification"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

else if (index==4)
{
    [item setTitle:@"Things-Todo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [item setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ThingsTodo"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

else if (index==5)
{
    [item setTitle:@"Search" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [item setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Search"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}


[item setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-(imageSize.height+(-20)), -10.0, -(imageSize.height+space), 10.0)];

CGSize titleSize=[item.titleLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: item.titleLabel.font}];

CGRect txtLabelframe=item.titleLabel.frame;
item.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, -(txtLabelframe.size.width+txtLabelframe.origin.x)/2, 10.0, - titleSize.width);

tabbuttonX=tabbuttonX+item.frame.size.width;


return item;
}
```

I want to make my font is in same size, But if I make those fonts in same size its truncate from the middle and middle of the text shows as dots. How can I make those fonts looks like in same size and show the full text in the button.

Please help me. This is my output for this code.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't add button title, you have to add another label as subview to the button

```
UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-10, button.frame.size.height-20, 100, 30)];//adjust the frame as you required
[label2 setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
label2.text = @"lengthy string is here";
[label2 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:button.titleLabel.font.fontName size:button.titleLabel.font.pointSize]];
[button addSubview:label2];
```

If the label touches the near button, Use this code

```
UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-10, button.frame.size.height-20, 150, 60)]; //adjust the frame as your string length
[label2 setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
NSMutableAttributedString *muAtrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"lengthy string\nshould be here"];
label2.numberOfLines = 0;
[label2 setAttributedText:muAtrStr];
[label2 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:button.titleLabel.font.fontName size:button.titleLabel.font.pointSize]];
[button addSubview:label2];
```

Comment: Please consider adding some detail to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First try to remove this line

```
item.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

I guess that the font will now remain equal size but gets clipped ?

Try to use the iOS Simulator debug option "Color Blended Layer" or the Xcode 6 View Debugging Option and see if the label is big enough.

Ah and methods usually starts with a lower case letter ;)